# want to unzip a specific file from zipped file

Tags: perlscript

I have a directory where zipped file is placed. I want to extract it but I need only xml document from it. I am able to extract whole file but I need only xml file. I need it in perlscript only on windows platform.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have extracted all zip file and stored in temp folder. I want to extract all zip file but I need only xml from that not all files.

Comment: You simply reworded what's in your question. Show us some code that you wrote and highlight what it's not working with that solution